# Apache Camel Rest endpoint with DSL in Spring Boot adds /camel to the path

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm trying to build a module to plug into a Spring Boot application. This module should expose some REST endpoints and I'm trying out building them with Camel because I don't want to have to add things to web.xml, etc.

```
restConfiguration().component("servlet")
      .contextPath("/my")
      .apiContextPath("/api-doc")
      .apiProperty("api.title", "My REST API")
      .apiProperty("cors", "true")
      .apiContextRouteId("my-api")
      .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);

rest("/my").description("My REST Services")
      .get("foo/{id}").route().routeId("foo")
      .to("direct:foo");

from("direct:foo")
      .process(new FooParamParser())
      .log("Done");
```

The problem I'm having is that instead of being at /my/foo/123?status=abc I have to hit it at /camel/my/foo/123?status=abc.

It's doing this because it's defaulting to using the Camel Servlet as the REST endpoint from the DSL, and I'm fine with that, but I don't want it to put the "/camel" at the start of my path. I should note that this behavior is the same with or without the `.component("servlet")`

Any way to change that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can control this in your application.properties or application.yml

e.g

```
camel.component.servlet.mapping.contextPath=/api/*
```

Reference https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/examples/camel-example-spring-boot-rest-jpa/src/main/resources/application.yml

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make it specific to this instance rather than global? We may have several of these add-on modules and each should be under its own context path.

Comment: I don't quite understand the concept of instance/global in your setup, but you could use /* in properties, if there isn't any other conflict and then set the distinct context path  for each service  in the DSL

Answer (score 3):

With Spring Boot 2.7.2+ and Apache Camel 3.18.0+, the key is now :

```
camel.servlet.mapping.context-path=/api/*
```

instead of

```
camel.component.servlet.mapping.contextPath=/api/*
```