# Cannot change REST context path in Apache Camel 3.14.0 Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

The dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    implementation("org.apache.camel:camel-core:3.14.0")
    implementation("org.apache.camel:camel-openapi-java:3.14.0")

    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.13.1")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.1")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.13.1")

    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

    implementation("org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-spring-boot-starter:3.14.0")
    implementation("org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-servlet-starter:3.14.0")
    implementation("org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-jackson-starter:3.14.0")
    implementation("org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-http-starter:3.14.0")
    implementation("org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-bean-validator-starter:3.14.0")
}
```

Attempts at changing from prop files:
`apache-camel-spring-boot/src/main/resources/application.properties`:

```
camel.component.servlet.mapping.contextPath=/test/*
camel.component.servlet.mapping.context-path=/test/*
```

`apache-camel-spring-boot/src/main/resources/application.yml`:

```
camel:
  component:
    servlet:
      mapping:
        contextPath: /test/*
```

The actual REST configuration:

```
@Component
public class CamelRouter extends RouteBuilder {

  @Override
  public void configure() throws Exception {

    restConfiguration()
        .component("servlet")
        .contextPath("test")
        .host("localhost")
        .port(8080)
        .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
        .enableCORS(true);

    rest("/users").description("User REST service")
        .produces("application/json")
        .get()
        .outType(String.class)
        .to("bean:myService?method=find")
  }
}
```

But the only URL that works is: http://localhost:8080/camel/users

Why is http://localhost:8080/test/users returning a 404 when I've changed the context path of Camel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added to `apache-camel-spring-boot/src/main/resources/application.properties`:

```
camel.servlet.mapping.context-path=/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Small addition to the accepted answer. Below Spring Boot 2.7.2 or Apache Camel 3.18.0, the key is:

`camel.component.servlet.mapping.contextPath=/*`

else it is

`camel.servlet.mapping.context-path=/*`

as stated by Thomas [Apache Camel Rest endpoint with DSL in Spring Boot adds /camel to the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798079/apache-camel-rest-endpoint-with-dsl-in-spring-boot-adds-camel-to-the-path). So in my case I was at spring boot version 2.4.0 and apache camel 3.7.3 and I had to use "camel.component.servlet.mapping.context-path".